# Unexpected ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, concurrentmodification

Not sure why I'm getting this exception.  The issue is that sometimes `onClose` is called prior to `closeAllOpenSessions`.  `onClose` operates normally, removing the specified element from `_openSessions`.  However, when `closeAllSessions` is called a `ConcurrentModificationException` is generated when we attempt to loop over `_openSessions.`

The exception does not occur when I comment out the remove statement.  Considering how both these operations are protected by the same mutex, I am unsure why this is happening.  What am I missing?

```
class B
{
    protected void onClose(Session session, List<WebSocketSessionStateful> openSessions) throws IOException
    {

        Iterator<WebSocketSessionStateful> openSessionsElements = openSessions.iterator();
        while(openSessionsElements.hasNext())
        {
            WebSocketSessionStateful openSession = openSessionsElements.next();
            if(session.equals(openSession.getSession()))
            {
                openSessionsElements.remove(); // comment me out to not throw exception
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    protected static void closeAllOpenSessions(List<WebSocketSessionStateful> openSessions) throws IOException
    {

        for(WebSocketSessionStateful openSession : openSessions) // exception generated here
        {
            openSession.getSession().close(new CloseReason(CloseReason.CloseCodes.GOING_AWAY, ""));
        }
    }
}

class A extends B
{
    private static final Object _endpointOperationMutex = new Object();

    private static final List<WebSocketSessionStateful> _openSessions = new ArrayList<WebSocketSessionStateful>();

    public void onClose(Session session, EndpointConfig config) throws IOException
    {
        synchronized (_endpointOperationMutex)
        {
            super.onClose(session, _openSessions);
        }
    }

    static void closeSessions() throws IOException
    {
        synchronized (_endpointOperationMutex)
        {
            WebSocketEndpointBase.closeAllOpenSessions(_openSessions);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you remove an element from a list while iterating over the list, you get a ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `closeAllOpenSesions()` method, you're iterating over your `openSessions` collection and, for each element in it, calling `close()`, which of course causes your `onClose()` method to fire. You're then also iterating over and removing from `openSessions` with each call to that `onClose()` method - which is where your concurrent modification is coming from.

You can conceptualize the problem more clearly as follows:

```
Iterator outerLoop = coll.iterator(); 
while (outerLoop.hasNext) { 
    Iterator innerLoop = coll.iterator(); 
    while (innerLoop.hasNext()){ 
        innerLoop.remove(); //ConcurrentModificationException
     }
 }
```

This is no different than:

```
 for (Object o : coll)
     for (Object p : coll) 
         if (p.someBoolean()) remove(p); //ConcurrentModificationException
```

You can't have two iterators iterating over *the same collection* simultaneously. If you do, a `ConcurrentModificationException` will be thrown if the inner loop removes an element that the outer loop is expecting to iterate over.

At a glance, I don't see why you need to iterate over `openSessions` within `B.onClose()`. Why should `B.onClose()` be responsible for closing all open sessions? Shouldn't that be done in  `closeAllOpenSessions()`?

Comment: Good catch on openSession.getSession().close causing onClose() to be called. I thought onClose() would only be called in response to the client closing the connection, not the server.  But it seems it is called when the server closes the connection as well.   In this light the concurrent modification makes sense to me.  Thanks.